# Problem with nginx as reverse proxy and few vps with docker

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have so much problem to correctly configure nginx, which is working as reverse proxy.

Server Architecture:

1. Nginx Reverse Proxy (with public IP, and gate for private network)
2. VPS with java as backend on Docker | expose 8090
3. VPS with vue.js as frontend on Docker | expose 8080

nginx configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name some-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/some-domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host X.X.X.3;
        proxy_pass http://X.X.X.3:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    }
}

server {
    listen 8090;
    server_name some-domain.com;
    location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host some-domain.com;
        proxy_pass http://X.X.X.2:8090;
        proxy_redirect off;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

    }
}
```

Domain: "some-domain.com" after opened looking good, front is working, but after I try to log in, and click on "sign-in" I'm getting in web console → network, OPTIONS request instead POST.

Let me know if you need more additional information.

I tried different solutions regarding the nginx configuration, but now I feel like I'm getting lost so that's why I wrote here.